# VB.NET: Prepend a string to all strings in a list of strings. Is there an existing method that does this?

Tags: vb.net, string, list, methods

I have a list of strings. For each string in that list, I want to prepend another string. I wrote a method to do it, but I was wondering if there was something already in .NET I could use to do this. It seems like something that could be built in, but I was not able to find anything.

Here is the method I wrote:

```
Private Function PrependToAllInList(ByRef inputList As List(Of String), ByRef prependString As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim returnList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    For Each inputString As String In inputList
        returnList.Add(String.Format("{0}{1}", prependString, inputString))
    Next
    Return returnList
End Function
```

It works, but I would rather use built in functions whenever possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Go with that and get on with the next task then! *grins*

Comment: Granted, you don't want to spend *all* of your time refactoring your code, but I think it's a good sign when a developer says "there must be a better way to do this" and then seeks to find out. When this becomes a habit, you will constantly become a better developer.

Comment: I am just trying to refactor some code. :) Something did not seem right about using that method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use LINQ (.NET 3.5 or greater), you can use a simple LINQ query to do the work for you:

```
Dim qry = stringList.Select(Function(s) "prepend this " & s)
Dim returnList = qry.ToList()
```

By default, `Select()` will return an `IEnumerable(Of String)`, which should work.  If you really need the collection to be a list, you can include the `.ToList()` command.  However, if you only plan to iterate over the collection (e.g. `For Each s As String in qry`), there's no need to take on the expense of converting it back to a list.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks! I have not used LINQ before, so I did not think to look there.

Comment: @Jeremy LINQ is great! Any time you would use a `For Each` loop, you can probably use `LINQ`. Check out [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688088.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
returnList = strlistList.Aggregate(New List(Of String), _
                 Function(list, s) list.Add("prepend this " & s) )
```

(note, I'm a C# prog, so I'm not sure about the syntax)

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is a mapping function, I've not come across any predefined mapping functions in vb.net, but you could achieve this in either the manner you have or using a lambda expression, delegates or LINQ.

There's a great blog post here on use of delegates for this purpose at http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2006/12/08/18587.aspx

The joy of this is it'll work in .NET 2.0 - but it's not nearly as elegant as LINQ which can be used in 3.5 and up...

```
inputList.Select(Function(s) String.Format("{0}{1}", pre, s).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.Insert instead of your String.Format to get it closer to what you expected.

[String.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you can use [string.concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx) to concatenate two strings, rather than string.format.

So instead of

```
String.Format("{0}{1}", prependString, inputString)
```

you could just put

```
String.Concat(prependString, inputString)
```

...as you seem keen to keep your code as clean as possible :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on String.Concat.